# phpmyadmin interface is not opening properly on mac

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin interface is not opening properly. Also, it doesn't click anywhere.
I can't access the tables
I tried different browsers and redownloaded. And it didn't.

*the screenshot is as follows:*

[image]

Comment: Mac OS version? phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: macOS Catalina
Version 10.15.7

phpMyAdmin 5.1.1

it was working before. It was the first time.

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin interface is not opening properly. I tried different browsers and redownloaded. And it didn't.